# Block using Nuxt3 group pages middleware

Tags: nuxtjs3

There are two user types, id 1 or id 0, so some routes are blocked for a specific user.

I'm using nuxt3.

My pages are organized like this: /profile/creator/*
/profile/user/*

I want to block all subpages that come in the creator's or user's folders, so only the permitted user can access

Help creating the middleware